# Counter lines on vector tiles with shortbread and tilemaker

Tags: vector-tiles

I am trying to create vector tiles. Following https://shortbread-tiles.org/make-vectortiles/, I have managed to do so for a small region.

I am now wondering if there is any way to add contour lines.
I found the guide http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Contours, but if I understand it correctly, tilemaker need to integrate and process a source file.

Does anybody know a better guide? Is there a better approach on how to add contour lines on vector lines?